# How to discard sites when there is overlap between buffers?

Tags: arcgis-desktop, arcgis-10.2, point, buffer, select

I have 1,000 sites in a landscape that were sampled along a road.
However, I think my sites are too close together. A lack of independence between my sites many be influencing my statistical models.

I would therefore like to select the maximum number of sites that don't overlap each other (500m buffers). I am using ArcGIS 10.2.

How can I do this?

Answer (score 1):

Use the buffer tool to create your 500m buffer polygons. Then use the intersect tool with your buffer layer as the only input. The output from the tool will be all the buffers that are overlapping with attribute information for each of the polygons that can be used to link back to your original plots.

[image: Buffer overlap example]